# Automatically close comments on articles older than X days also hides comments

Tags: wordpress, comments

I am using WordPress 4.0.

My goal is to disable new comments on posts that are older than 14 days, but still have existing comments, that were made in the allowed time frame, be visible.

In Settings->Discussion, there is an option to "Automatically close comments on articles older than x days".  I have selected this option, and set x to be 14 days.

I thought this would simply close comments on posts older than 14 days , but it is also **hiding** the comments for posts older than 14 days.

I have checked the theme's comments.php file, and I don't see anything that would indicate that it is the theme that is hiding the comments.

I am relatively new to Stack Overflow.  I have googled this question all day, and searched Stack Overflow, and cannot find an answer.  So I guess my question is, if the code that is causing this behavior is not in comments.php, where would it be?

Thank you.

Comment: That is quite strange, which theme are you using?

Comment: @Anand I wish I could delete my dumb posts.  I figured out the answer after I posted, of course.  I am using Vivid by Bluthemes.  The problem was not in comments.php.  The problem was in single.php.  At the end of single.php, there is a call to comments_template(), but only if comments are open.  There is no else statement in the case that comments are closed, so no call was being made to comments_template() if comments were closed.  I had to add an else statement to single.php, and I think that fixed it.  Maybe this will help someone using Vivid by Bluthemes...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable comments on your posts after specific number of days, you can use this code for the purpose. Put this code in your theme's functions.php file.

```
<?php function autoclose_comments() {
    global $wpdb, $tableposts;

    if (!isset($tableposts))
        $tableposts = $wpdb->posts;

        $age = '21 DAY';

        $date = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL $age), INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE $tableposts SET comment_status = 'closed' WHERE comment_status = 'open' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_date < '$date'");
}
```

You can set `$age` as per your requirement.